# terraform: module variable as object

Tags: terraform

This is my module snippet:

`inputs.tf`:

```
variable "namespace" {
    type = object({
        metadata = object({
            name = string
        })
    })
}
```

`main.tf`:

```
resource "helm_release" "spark" {
    name       = "spark"
    repository = "https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami" 
    chart      = "spark"
    version    = "1.2.21"
    namespace  = var.namespace.metadata.name
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to get access to previously created `kubernetes_namespace`.

Into my environment workspace:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "this" {
    metadata {
        name = var.namespace
    }
}

module "spark" {
    source = "../modules/spark"

    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.this
    workers = 1
}
```

I'm getting this message when I'm trying to get plan:

```
➜  development terraform plan | xclip -selection clipboard

Error: Invalid value for module argument

  on main.tf line 14, in module "spark":
  14:     namespace = kubernetes_namespace.this

The given value is not suitable for child module variable "namespace" defined
at ../modules/spark/inputs.tf:1,1-21: attribute "metadata": object required.
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is reporting that the value you've assigned to the `namespace` variable is not compatible with its type constraint.

The `metadata` attribute of `kubernetes_namespace` seems to be defined as a list of objects rather than as a single object, and so automatic type conversion here is impossible. One way you could proceed here is to change your variable's type to match the resource type schema, like this:

```
variable "namespace" {
    type = object({
        metadata = list(object({
            name = string
        }))
    })
}
```

We can see in the provider implementation that [this block is defined as having `MaxItems: 1`](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-kubernetes/blob/56b543613dbbf4bb0b079349f57ffe2ea12fc243/kubernetes/schema_metadata.go#L75) and so as long as that remains true (which seems likely) you can expect `var.namespace.metadata` to be either an empty list or a single-item list, which you could write in a local variable for easier use elsewhere in the module:

```
locals {
  namespace_name = var.namespace.metadata[0].name
}
```

The above will make `local.namespace_name` refer to the given namespace name, or the expression will fail if the given namespace doesn't have a `metadata` block, because there will be no element `[0]` in that case.

---

The above is a lot of complexity just to get access to the namespace *name*. A structure like the above could be useful if you expect to need to use other attributes of the `kubernetes_namespace` object in future, but if you can get by with just the name then it could be helpful to simplify this to be just a single string variable with the namespace name directly:

```
variable "namespace_name" {
  type = string
}
```

...and you can let the caller worry about how to obtain that name:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "this" {
    metadata {
        name = var.namespace
    }
}

module "spark" {
    source = "../modules/spark"

    namespace_name = kubernetes_namespace.this.metadata.name
    workers        = 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to pass `kubernetes_namespace.this.metadata.0.name` to the module instead and just have the module variable take a string. That should give you the required dependency chain and also simplify things a little.

So your module's `inputs.tf` should have:

```
variable "namespace" {
  type = string
}
```

and then you call it like this:

```
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "this" {
    metadata {
        name = var.namespace
    }
}

module "spark" {
    source = "../modules/spark"

    namespace = kubernetes_namespace.this.metadata.0.name
    workers   = 1
}
```